# AIOHTTP Server - Jinja templates for raise conditions

Tags: python, python-3.x, error-handling, jinja2, aiohttp

In creating a site with AIOHTTP Web, I might define a route and raise an error like:

```
async def index(request):
    if some_error_happened:
        raise web.HTTPException(body=b'Some error happened.')
    context = {'page_title': "My Site"}
    response = aiohttp_jinja2.render_template('index.html', request, context)
    return response
```

This will show the text I specified for `body` but how can I use Jinja2 with it like normal routes?

I found the module [jinja2_error](https://pypi.org/project/jinja2-error/) but I don't see how to use it in the context of an aiohttp route.

Answer (score 0):

Use `aiohttp_jinja2.render_string`:

```
async def index(request):
    if some_error_happened:
        raise web.HTTPBadRequest(
            text=aiohttp_jinja2.render_template(
                'index.html', 
                request, 
                {"error": "Some error happened"},
            )
        )
    context = {'page_title': "My Site"}
    response = aiohttp_jinja2.render_template('index.html', request, context)
    return response
```